# The code clearly has an unreachable statement in it yet compiles - why?

Tags: java, exception, unreachable-statement

The statement on Line 2 will never execute but the compiler doesn't complain:

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        throwE();
//        throw new Exception();  // Line 1
        doStuff();                // Line 2
    }

    static void throwE() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Throwing an Exception");
        throw new Exception();
//        doStuff();              // Line 3
    }

    static void doStuff(){ System.out.println("Doing stuff"); }
}
```

On the other hand, uncommenting either Line 1 or Line 3 leads to the 'unreachable statement' compile-time error.

I wonder why the compiler is so inconsistent...

Comment: In the first case, the compiler knows only that there is a method which throws `Exception`, but there is no guarantee that this method does it.

In the second case, the exception will be thrown anyway.

Comment: Also, [How can I detect dead code after always-throwing methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705520/how-can-i-detect-dead-code-after-always-throwing-methods)

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko Makes perfect sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler doesn't analyze any method call (such as `throwE()`) to find out whether it will always throw an exception, since that's not practical. There might be a chain of 10 (or a 100) method calls where the last method always throws an exception. Would you still expect the compiler to determine that any statement following `throwE()` is unreachable in such case?

Only if the current method always throws an exception directly, any statements following the throw statement are deemed unreachable.